# SEO when forward domain in global rank vs local region?

Tags: seo, domains, redirects, https, search-engines

I have one .ir domain and google map services not works on .ir domains, I want to get .org domain and set SSL EV for this .org domain then forward .ir to .org domain. one web app is installed on this domain.

Is SEO for .ir domain get penalty (because .ir in local region get more Alexa rank than .org)? what is the best tips for SEO? Is domain change SEO results or just IP is important?

Comment: Background info on Google Maps blocking `.ir` domains: http://techrasa.com/2018/06/11/iran-weekly-recap-google-maps-terminates-ir-domains-32k-online-businesses-more/

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister we should by another domain to use google map services.

Answer (score 1):

The TLD (top level domain) is irrelevant to Alexa's ranking. That rank is determined by your site's traffic, particularly the number of unique visitors and pageviews over a 3 month period.

If you permanently redirect all of the traffic from .ir to .org you will most likely lose some of your SEO ranking, at least initially. Once search engines are able to process and reindex the redirected content you will probably recover most of your search ranking. Alexa rank, on the other hand will start fresh as this is tracked by domain and not IP.